Handle the trimming in NestJS using Typescript (DTO files)
Below is the create-user-dto file where I have used to create the creation of an account including a username, password and a role. Done using arrays. Although I have set it up still it shows' white space in my array.
import { Transform } from "class-transformer";
import { IsString, MinLength, MaxLength, Matches, IsIn } from "class-validator";

export class CreateUserDto{
    @IsString()
    @MinLength(4)
    @MaxLength(20)
    @Transform(({ value }) => value.trim())
    username: string;
  
    @IsString()
    @MinLength(8)
    @MaxLength(20,{
      message: 'Password can contain only 20 characters',
    })
    @Matches(/(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*)/, {
      message: 'Password too weak',
    })
    @Transform(({ value }) => value.trim())
    password: string;
  
    
    @IsString()
    @IsIn(['Teacher', 'Admin'], {
      message: 'Role must be either Teacher or Admin'
    })
    @Transform(({ value }) => value.trim())
    role: 'Teacher' | 'Admin';
}

Controller class code: -
@Post('register')
    @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({transform:true, whitelist: true}))
    async createUser(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<string> { 
        const existingUser = this.userService.findUser(createUserDto.username);
        if(existingUser){
            throw new BadRequestException("Username already exists");
        }

        this.userService.createUser(createUserDto.username, createUserDto.password, createUserDto.role);
        return 'User created successfully';
    }

Once I save the password with spaces it should save without the spaces right. Still the array has saved the password with an empty space.

Can you give an example of a password? Trim will only remove spaces from start and end of a string

Also, would this help you solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65486947/nestjs-transform-a-property-using-validationpipe-before-validation-execution-dur

Thank you, I thought that trim would eliminate any whitespace. What option will be the best to eliminate spaces between character,
Ex: - password:'Hello 123'

This worked for me,
@Transform(({ value }) => value.replace(/\s+/g, ''))This worked for me.
Is this a good practice or any other option I can work with?

Yeah thats what I was going to suggest. And yes its good practice.
Consider adding an answer to your question explaining how it was solved so future users will find it helpful :)

It is bizarre that it doesn't work with trim. Sounds like a bug
